# r long to wide time series data with start and stop time columns

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, data-transform, mutate

I like to reshape a time series data from long to wide format , with columns such as `StartTime` and `StopTime`. All variables measured during the same time interval (`StartTime`, `StopTime`) to be in the same line.

For example if this is my dataset

```
       Id      Time     Status     Col1
       10      2012     4          2

       11      2009     2          5
       11      2010     2          5

       12      2004     2          2
       12      2009     2          3
       12      2011     2          1
       12      2018     2          3

       17      2018     2          3
       17      2020     2          1
```

Expecting a dataset like this

```
       Id      From   To      Status      Col1
       10      2012   2012        4          2

       11      2009   2010        2          5
      
       12      2004   2009        2          2
       12      2009   2011        2          3
       12      2011   2018        2          1
       12      2018   2018        2          3
      
       17      2018   2020        2          3
       17      2020   2020        2          1
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to create a `lead` column after grouping by 'Id'

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% mutate(To = if(n() == 1) Time else 
     lead(Time, default = last(Time)), .before = Status) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  rename(From = Time) %>%
  filter(!is.na(To))
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why in id 12, there is no 2018-2018.

```
df %>%
   group_by(Id)%>%
   mutate(From = Time,To = lead(Time, def = last(Time)),.after=Id, Time = NULL)

# A tibble: 9 × 5
# Groups:   Id [4]
     Id  From    To Status  Col1
  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int>
1    10  2012  2012      4     2
2    11  2009  2010      2     5
3    11  2010  2010      2     5
4    12  2004  2009      2     2
5    12  2009  2011      2     3
6    12  2011  2018      2     1
7    12  2018  2018      2     3
8    17  2018  2020      2     3
9    17  2020  2020      2     1
```

Comment: you are not wrong.